# C Program - How to get the second occurrence in strtok()?

Tags: c

I have a text file like this:

```
/www/test.php = 24323
```

with `strtok(myfile," = ")` it only prints the first occurrence which is `/www/test.php`, how can I print the second occurrence which is `24323` ?

**NEW PROBLEM:**

```
char * name;
char *def_size;
name = strtok (line," = ");
def_size = strtok(NULL, " = ");
stat(name, &st);
if (st.st_size != def_size) {
    printf("File size doesn't match\n");
}
```

When I compile that, I get:

> test.c: In function ‘main’: test.c:23:24: warning: comparison between
>   pointer and integer
>            if (st.st_size != def_size) {
>                           ^~

How do I fix this ? Sorry I'm really new to C programming

Comment: So what in the documentation of that function did you not understand? Where is your code? Which **specific** problem do you have?

Comment: Seconding what @Olaf said. This is very well-documented in all the common C standard library resources available online (and under `man strtok(3)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the first argument of `strtok` to `NULL`. It would look like this:

```
strtok(NULL, " = ");
```

Of course, you would still have to keep your call to `strtok(myfile, " = ");` but any subsequent calls to `strtok` with `NULL` as the first argument will continue from the last point of the previously specified string.

Example:

```
printf("%s", strtok(myfile, " = ");     // prints "/www/test.php"
printf("%s", strtok(NULL, " = ");       // prints "24323"
```

You also cannot compare a string to an integer. You need to use `atoi` like so:

```
if (st.st_size != atoi(def_size) {
    printf("File size doesn't match\n");
}
```

Comment: can you take a look at my question once again ? I've got a new problem

Comment: BTW why does this merit a downvote?

Comment: @hillz I did, and updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use loop to print every part.
Below is the code given for printing all token

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char str[80] = "/www/test.php = 24323";
   const char s[2] = "=";
   char *token;

   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(str, s);

   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL ) 
   {
      printf( " %s\n", token );

      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: can you take a look at my question once again ? I've got a new problem

Comment: @hillz: We are no tutoring or interactive debugging service. Please read the documentation and try to understand it. If you don't understand it, first do some research on your own before asking. Follow site-rules.